# Custom attributes with class reference

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a custom attribute that behaves like *tools:context*, that is with

- Android Studio auto complete functionallity
- Project classname reference
- Support for auto refactory in case I change my class directory

This is my resources.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="RecyclerView">
    <attr name="adapter" format="string"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

This is the usage

```
    <example.com.br.appname.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/accounts"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         app:adapter="example.com.br.appname.AccountAdapter" >
    </example.com.br.appname.RecyclerView>
```

I've tried to use the format *reference* but it didn't compile as well.

*Error:(17, 22) String types not allowed (at 'adapter' with value 'example.com.br.appname.AccountAdapter').*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think this is possible currently. Other similar custom attrs I can think of, for instance `app:layout_behavior` from the design library, or simply `app:layoutManager` from `RecyclerView` all require the full classname, with none of your requirements.

It might be better to store these in a `strings` resource file, and remember to check it when refactoring class names.

You can consider filing a feature request, since Android Studio has this functionality in special cases (`tools:context`, `class` in `<view>` and `<fragment>` tags, classes in Manifest...), but I doubt they would add a new attribute format just for this.

Comment: Well ... I think I will need to give up doing it this way ... Maybe I will need to do it programmatically and not in the layout file ... that is sad :(

Comment: If this is for your own app (not a library) and you have a reasonably small amount of adapters, you could use a `enum` attribute (for example, `FloatingActionButton` has an enum for size, `mini` and `normal`) enumerating all your adapters with short names.

Answer (score 2):

so...

- apparently, YOU CAN!
- Google [does this too](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/aa68ab828873274a141f6463091abd4fa7315a9b/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L3746-L3748).
- Android Studio understands that the class is being referenced from XML

  - i.e.

    - `Refactor > Rename` works
    - `Find Usages` works
    - and so on...

don't specify a `format` attribute in **.../src/main/res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
        ....
        <attr name="give_me_a_class"/>
        ....
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

use it in some layout file **.../src/main/res/layout/activity__main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- make sure to use $ dollar signs for nested classes -->
    <MyCustomView
        app:give_me_a_class="class.type.name.Outer$Nested/>

    <MyCustomView
        app:give_me_a_class="class.type.name.AnotherClass/>

</SomeLayout>
```

parse the class in your view initialization code **.../src/main/java/.../MyCustomView.kt**

```
class MyCustomView(
        context:Context,
        attrs:AttributeSet)
    :View(context,attrs)
{
    // parse XML attributes
    ....
    private val giveMeAClass:SomeCustomInterface
    init
    {
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.ColorPreference,0,0).apply()
        {
            try
            {
                // very important to use the class loader from the passed-in context
                giveMeAClass = context::class.java.classLoader!!
                        .loadClass(getString(R.styleable.MyCustomView_give_me_a_class))
                        .newInstance() // instantiate using 0-args constructor
                        .let {it as SomeCustomInterface}
            }
            finally
            {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In AS 4.0 Canary, I had to declare the attr outside of the styleable as well for it to compile.

Comment: @TheWanderer Hey! Can you post an example please? or modify my answer, please? You're right, this solution is not working for me anymore, and my old code is breaking, but I'm not sure how to declare it outside the styleable...i just added `format="string"` for now.. Thank you!!

Comment: Just add an attr tag right under the opening resources tag with the same name and a format specified.